# How to regex link in php

Tags: php, regex

I have problem in regex php. Need regex code Recognize the link from string
My link : https://mywebsite.com/cargallery/subcat/

```
    if( preg_match( '/(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))(([^"]*cargallery[^"])*([\w_-]+)(\/|))?/', $requested_url,$mactches)) {
    // if url = https://mywebsite.com/cargallery/subcat/

    echo "true";

}else {
    //if  url= https://mywebsite.com/cargallery/subcat/dasdsad
    // or https://mywebsite.com/cargallery
    // or https://mywebsite.com
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I need regex if string is like https://mywebsite.com/cargallery/subcat/ return true. But if is like https://mywebsite.com/cargallery or https://mywebsite.com/cargallery/subcat/subsub return false

Comment: Then why do you need a regex? If it's a litteral exact match then just use an if or str_replace. I don't understand where the regex is supposed to fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your regex you could use [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string.

Without anchors your regex will match for example `https://mywebsite.com` and [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will return 1.

[`^(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))(([^"]*cargallery[^"])*([\w_-]+)(\/|))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/IiPU4o/1)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/eCWUU)

Answer (score 2):

Just use an if to see if it matches. No need to make it more complex than it is.

```
if($requested_url == "https://mywebsite.com/cargallery/$subcat/"){
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Subcat is variable :|

Comment: You didn't include that in your question nor was there anything that hinted that it was a variable. But my answer remains fairly untouched.

Comment: true. but i want use it for redirect and subcats is variable ,so i dont have exact name of subcat...

Comment: @HossinAsaadi so does it work? Can you accept the answer?